# auto retry connection

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I'm trying to build a checker via .NET using TCPCLIENT

For each email to check my app is making a connection between my server and the smtp server which means sometimes the smtp server dont response.

The question that im looking for is how to keep retrying to connect
if the connection missed .

Here is my code :

```
TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("smtp-in.orange.fr", 25);
string CRLF = "\r\n";
byte[] dataBuffer;

string ResponseString;
NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

/* Perform HELO to SMTP Server and get Response */
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO KirtanHere" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("mail from:<contact@contact.com>" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to implement try catch block inside for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < retryCount; i++)
{
   try
   {
       YourAction();
       break; // success
   }
   catch { /*ignored*/ }

   // give a little breath..
   Thread.Sleep(50); 
}
```

Looks ugly but pretty simple, and for some cases it is not recommended. You may want to try **[Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)**, this library allows you to express exception handling policies including Retry.

And also I want to point out that you've had never dispose disposable objects such as `NetworkStream` and `StreamReader`. Since you *will* run long running process, you **should** dispose them.

```
private static void YourAction()
{
   var tClient = new TcpClient("smtp-in.orange.fr", 25);
   const string CRLF = "\r\n";

   string ResponseString;
   using (var netStream = tClient.GetStream())
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(netStream))
   {
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

       /* Perform HELO to SMTP Server and get Response */
       var dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO KirtanHere" + CRLF);
       netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
       dataBuffer = BytesFromString("mail from:<contact@contact.com>" + CRLF);
       netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
       ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One Solution would be to use Polly library.

With Polly you need to configure Policy as in which scenarios, you want to retry.

Please specify you exception Policy something like below

```
var maxRetryAttempts = 3;
var pauseBetweenFailures = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()// Handle specific exception
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetryAttempts, i => pauseBetweenFailures);
```

Surround your code with

```
await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("smtp-in.orange.fr", 25);
string CRLF = "\r\n";
byte[] dataBuffer;
.....
});
```

For detailed explanation on how to use Polly, there is nice article ..

https://alastaircrabtree.com/implementing-the-retry-pattern-using-polly/